# Wrong time with DateTime

Tags: php, datetime, timestamp

I am creating notifications system and here is a task: get the time, when a notification was sent. I mean the following: 1 minute ago, 13 hours ago and so on. I have already made up a script but it shows wrong time. For example instead of showing '5 minutes ago' it shows '9 hours ago'. Here is the alrogithm:

1. Get old timestamp from database. Old timestamp is the time, when a
   notification was sent.
2. Get current users timestamp.
3. Get difference between them.
4. Echo result.

Here is the PHP code:

```
$fromdb = '1503737539'; //For this example think, that this variable is from database. 
//This timestamp was created 5 minutes earlier, so in result it should show '5 minutes ago'.

    $curr = new DateTime();
    $got2 = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$fromdb));
    $interval = $curr->diff($got2);
    echo $interval->format('%d')." days ".$interval->format('%h')." Hours ".$interval->format('%i')." Minutes ".$interval->format('%s')." Seconds";
```

The output is:

> 0 days 9 hours ....

instead of

> 0 days 0 hours 5 minutes ....

How can I fix that? I guess that this is a problem with timezones. But how can I guess guests timezone though?

Update:
Change code:
$got2 = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$fromdb));

And interesting fact: The more is actual difference, the less time it shows in output. For example: Old timestamp was created at 8:00 am, and current is 15:00 pm, it shows 0 days 1 hour in output.

Comment: there is mistake in your code. you format date without hours, minutes and seconds

$got2 = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d',$fromdb));

try

$got2 = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$fromdb));

Comment: @Dmitry so what is a proper way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think

```
date('Y-m-d',$fromdb)
```

broke your code.
Try

```
$got2->setTimestamp($fromdb)
```

Comment: setTimestamp() function fixed a problem. Also, changing format helped also. Thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 1):

there is mistake in your code. you format date without hours, minutes and seconds

```
$got2 = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d',$fromdb));
```

try

```
$got2 = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$fromdb));
```

Comment: This decreased time to 2 hours. But it should be 45 minutes.

Comment: It is because your timestamp 1503737539 was 4 hours ago.
        $fromdb = '1503737539';
        $curtime = time();
        echo ($curtime - $fromdb) / 60 / 60 . PHP_EOL;

Answer (score 1):

Try

> $date = new DateTime(); echo $date->format('U = Y-m-d H:i:s');
>
> $date->setTimestamp(1171502725);
>   echo $date->format('U = Y-m-d H:i:s');